# Handling large file uploads and sending to API

Tags: php, amazon-s3, upload, containers, amazon-lightsail

I'm stuck wondering what the best solution is to handling large file uploads and sending them to a third-party API. Any pointers on what would be a good solution would be very welcome. Thank you in advance.

The end goal is to send video files to this API - https://docs.bunny.net/reference/manage-videos#video_uploadvideo. The complication is that the files are often large - up to 5GB in size.

I have an existing website built in PHP7 that runs on a LAMP setup on Amazon Lightsail and I want to add a feature for users to upload video files.

Currently I'm uploading the files directly to Amazon S3 using a pre-signed URL. This part is working fine.

But I need to send the files to the API mentioned above. This is where I get stuck!

I think there's two options to explore - (1) find a way to upload directly to the API and skip the S3 upload or (2) continue with uploading to S3 first and then transfer to the API. But I'm not sure if option 1 is even possible or how to do option 2!

With option 1, I'm wondering if there's a way to upload the files from the users directly to the API. If I do this using the regular HTML form upload, then the files are stored temporarily on my server before I can use cURL through PHP to transfer them to the API. This is really time consuming and feels very inefficient. But I don't know how else to send the files to the API without them first being on my server. Maybe there's an option here that I don't know about!

With option 2, I can already upload large files directly to S3 with pre-signed URLs and this process seems to run fine. But I don't know how I would then send the file from S3 to the API. I can use an S3 trigger on new files. But when I looked at Lambda, they have a tiny file size limit. Because my site is hosted on Lightsail, I noticed they have a container option. But I don't know if that can be used for this purpose and if so, how.

Basically, I'm not sure what solution is best, nor how to proceed with that. And maybe there's an option 3 that I'm not aware of!

I would welcome your input.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If I were you I will use rsync (provided that I am allowed to set the required permissions in both sides)

Comment: The API appears to only allow PUT method uploads, so with a normal form submission this won't work. The provide JS code to perform the upload, which you could theoretically use on the client side - but since it needs your API access key as well, this is also not an option, because you don't want to expose your access key to the users of your site/app. This would only be a viable option, if each user had their own API key.

Comment: What is the use case here? why do you `need` to transfer this large file? can you share a location and method of access instead?

Comment: @KenLee - thank you, I will investigate rsync, but I'm not sure that it allows PUT which is required by the API

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your comments. Yeah, I don't don't JS can work because there's one API key for the service, not per user.

Comment: _" will investigate rsync, but I'm not sure that it allows PUT which is required by the API"_ - rsync is a tool to synchronize files between two servers, it is not suitable to talk to any HTTP based API in the first place.

Comment: @Erik - the use case is a need for users to upload videos and then for other users to play them back. The API is to upload to Bunny Stream which does all of the encoding and then makes it available in a secure player through their CDN. I could build all of that in AWS, but it would be a lot more complicated and expensive than a single file sent to the Bunny Stream API.